# Arithmetic language with Lex and Yacc

Tags: parsing, yacc, lex

I'm learning Lex and Yacc and I'm tryng to do this exercise.

I've to implement a Yacc for a language formed by arithmetic expressions built starting from:

identifiers,
numerical constants: natural numbers,
the 4 arithmetic operations,
exponent: **,
the analytic functions: sin, cos, tan,
brackets.
The order of priority between the various operators is defined in this way: for arithmetic operations the usual order applies, the exponent has priority over the trigonometric functions which in turn have priority over the product. All operations are associative on the left, minus the exponent that associates on the right.

The analyzer must return the tree of the syntactic structure of the expression received at the input.

This is my Lex code:

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include "y.tab.h"
%}

%%
[ \t]+   ; // ignore all whitespace

[a-z]+  { return ID;}
 
[0-9]+  { yylval = atoi(yytext); return NUMBER;}
 
%%
```

and this is my Yacc:

```
%{
#include "lex.yy.c"

void yyerror(const char *str){
fprintf(stderr,"errore: %s\n",str);}
int yywrap() {return 1;}
int main() { yyparse();}

%}

/* DEF*/    
%token NUMBER ID

%left '-' '+'
%left '*' '/'
%left 'sin' 'cos' 'tan'
%right '**'


%% /* RULES */
%%
E : T        {
                printf("Result = %d\n", $$);
                return 0;
            }

T: 
    T '+' T{$$=$1+$3; }
    | T '-' T {$$=$1-$3; }
    | T '*' T{$$=$1*$3; }   
    | T '/' T{$$=$1/$3; }
    | '(' T ')' { $$ = $2; }    
    | T '**' T {$$=$1*$3; }
    | 'sin' T 
    | 'cos' T
    | 'tan' T   
    | '(' T ')' { $$ = $2; }
    | NUMBER { $$ = $1; }
    | ID { $$ = $1; };      

%%

int main() {
    printf("Enter the expression\n");
    yyparse();
}
 
/* For printing error messages */
int yyerror(char* s) {
    printf("\nExpression is invalid\n");
}
```

I don't know how to calculate the trigonometric functions, I don't know if is correct how I handle priority between the various operators and the brackets.

Can somebody help me ? I'm just learning sorry for stupid errors

Comment: What does this have to do with Haskell? What's the point of trigonometric functions if all your values are integers? If you want the syntactic structure, why do you just evaluate the result?

Comment: Sorry for the tag mistake! it is simply the delivery of the exercise. Isn't the purpose of yyparse() function build the syntactic structure ?

Comment: The parser built by yacc/bison does exactly what you tell it to do in the various semantic rules you write. It could directly evaluate an arithmetic expression. It could compile a program into three-address instructions. It could syntax colour a program text. Or whatever. Building a syntactic structure, such as an AST, is a very common use case, and it is certainly within the possibilities. But nothing is automatic. The parser parses, and reports each parser reduction. The rest is up to you.

Comment: Presumably this exercise was given to you after a discussion of what a syntactic structure is and how to build it. You should review that material. If you were just thrown into the ocean to see if you sink or swim, then you might have a legitimate complaint. I don't know anything about the state of higher education in whatever country you live in, and not a lot about the current state of higher education in the country I live in (it's been a long time since I passed through that) but I have the impression that there is still some attempt to give students the necessary background.

Comment: If you have no other materials, you could consider [John Levine's Flex and Bison](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/flex-bison/9780596805418/), published by O'Reilly, which does a reasonable job of explaining the structure of bison-generated parsers and then shows how to build an Abstract Syntax Tree, with a reasonably amount of detail. So that's about 80 pages of reading. :-)